# Unity.Mathematics/uint2x3.gen.cs' is a binary file instead of a text file after i updated my unity editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

After i updated my unity editor from 2021 lts to 2022 lts i getting this problem. i tried few things. reinstalled unity editor, deleted library but nothing worked
error CS2015: 'C:\Users\MyName\GameProject\Library/PackageCache/com.unity.mathematics@1.2.6/Unity.Mathematics/uint2x3.gen.cs' is a binary file instead of a text file
error CS2015: 'C:\Users\MyName\GameProject\Library/PackageCache/com.unity.mathematics@1.2.6/Unity.Mathematics/half4.gen.cs' is a binary file instead of a text file

Comment: have you tried completely deleting the `Library` folder? No worries it is just a cache that is completely regenerated when you open the project again in Unity. The Version bump most probably came along with also a version update in the packages and this always causes troubles with the Library cache

Answer (score 0):

My point of view is the same as DerHugo

Please try to delete `Library` according to the path in the error prompt, which will clean up the package cache. And does not affect your use of unity, because when you open the project again in Unity, it will be completely re -generated.

If this still does not work, please try the "Advanced" of the "Advanced" window of the bag manager to reinvigorate the package to the default value